# Looking for a safe way to delete a parquet file from Delta Lake

Tags: amazon-s3, delta-lake

as the title says I'm looking for a safe way to delete parquet files on a Delta Lake, correct because I don't want to corrupt my Delta Lake.

This is what happened, some days ago some partitions had to be backfilled but forgot to delete the contents of one of those prior to this process, delete/refill is the last resource I want to try right now.

I know by the last modification date which files I need to delete, but if I delete them from S3 I will corrupt the partition/table and generate an inconsistency against the manifest.
What would be the "uncorrupting" way to delete those files?
I'm currently working on spark.
Thanks!

Comment: How did you perform the backfill?

Comment: Ask another team to resend some events, that's what I'm trying to avoid, plus want to lear how to delete files, it could be useful in the future, thanks!